# enum like structure that represents a tree

Tags: python, pydantic

i want to represent a constant tree of strings, not a dynamic one.

for example:

structure -> house,tower

house -> green_house, yellow_house

tower -> small_tower, big_tower

where each of them is a string (house='house')

the goal is to be able to access the tree in such way:

```
structure.house.yellow_house
```

which will then give me a string of their enum values:

```
'structure.house.yellow_house'
```

what might be a good way to define such structure?

Answer (score 0):

My first naive thought would be to use a class hierarchy.

```
class Structure:
    @classmethod
    def name(cls):
        if cls == Structure:
            return cls.__name__
        else:
            return cls.__bases__[0].name() + '.' +  cls.__name__

class House(Structure):
    pass

class Tower(Structure):
    pass
    
class GreenHouse(House):
    pass

class YellowHouse(House):
    pass

class SmallTower(Tower):
    pass

class BigTower(Tower):
    pass

print(BigTower.name())  # Structure.Tower.BigTower
print(House.name())  # Structure.House
print(Structure.name())  # Structure
```

Maybe this is abusing the functionality of classes, but it's simple. Access is a bit different than what you specified, this just uses the leaf name, e.g., `BigTower` rather than writing the whole tree path `Structure.Tower.BigTower`. It's more compact, but maybe it could create namespace collisions depending on your use case.